# I can't figure out why my dapper Multi-Mapper is giving an exception

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to rewrite all my EntityFramework Core queries to Dapper. On this one query I am getting an exception that I can't figure out. Data is returned on the sister EF Core query. This looks like to me that I don't have my Multi-Mapper set up correctly.

Here is my dapper function:

```
public sealed class DapperFunctions : IDisposable
{
    private IDbConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;

    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public DapperFunctions(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ILogger logger)
    {
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.ForContext<DapperFunctions>().Information("Initializing DapperFunctions");

        if (FluentMapper.EntityMaps.IsEmpty)
        {
            FluentMapper.Initialize(config =>
            {
                config.AddMap(new OrderMap());
                config.AddMap(new OrderDetailMap());
                config.AddMap(new BillToAddressMap());
                config.AddMap(new ShipToAddressMap());
                config.AddMap(new ReserveDocumentMap());
            });
        }
    }

    
    public IEnumerable<OrderDto> GetInvoicesMultiMapping(string customerId)
    {
        string sql =
            @$"SELECT [order].[SOPTYPE],
                   [order].[SOPNUMBE],
                   [order].[INVODATE],
                   [order].[ACTLSHIP],
                   [order].[DUEDATE],
                   [order].[LOCNCODE],
                   [order].[CUSTNMBR],
                   [order].[CUSTNAME],
                   [order].[SLPRSNID],
                   [order].[PYMTRCVD],
                   [order].[PYMTRMID],
                   [order].[SUBTOTAL],
                   [order].[FRTAMNT],
                   [order].[TAXAMNT],
                   [order].[DOCAMNT],
                   [detail].[ITEMNMBR],
                   [detail].[SOPTYPE],
                   [detail].[SOPNUMBE],
                   [detail].[ReqShipDate],
                   [detail].[ITEMDESC],
                   [detail].[UOFM],
                   [detail].[LOCNCODE],
                   [detail].[UNITPRCE],
                   [detail].[XTNDPRCE],
                   [detail].[QUANTITY],
                   [billtoaddr].[ShipToName] AS[BillToName],
                   [billtoaddr].[CUSTNMBR],
                   [billtoaddr].[ADRSCODE],
                   [billtoaddr].[CNTCPRSN],
                   [billtoaddr].[ADDRESS1],
                   [billtoaddr].[ADDRESS2],
                   [billtoaddr].[ADDRESS3],
                   [billtoaddr].[COUNTRY],
                   [billtoaddr].[CITY],
                   [billtoaddr].[STATE],
                   [billtoaddr].[ZIP],
                   [billtoaddr].[PHONE1],
                   [billtoaddr].[PHONE2],
                   [billtoaddr].[PHONE3],
                   [billtoaddr].[FAX],
                   [shiptoaddr].[ShipToName],
                   [shiptoaddr].[CUSTNMBR],
                   [shiptoaddr].[ADRSCODE],
                   [shiptoaddr].[CNTCPRSN],
                   [shiptoaddr].[ADDRESS1],
                   [shiptoaddr].[ADDRESS2],
                   [shiptoaddr].[ADDRESS3],
                   [shiptoaddr].[COUNTRY],
                   [shiptoaddr].[CITY],
                   [shiptoaddr].[STATE],
                   [shiptoaddr].[ZIP],
                   [shiptoaddr].[PHONE1],
                   [shiptoaddr].[PHONE2],
                   [shiptoaddr].[PHONE3],
                   [shiptoaddr].[FAX],
                   CAST([reserv].[DocumentOrigin] AS INT) AS [Origin]
            FROM[dbo].[SOP10100] AS [order]
                INNER JOIN[dbo].[SOP10200] AS [detail]
                    ON[order].[SOPTYPE] = [detail].[SOPTYPE]
                       AND[order].[SOPNUMBE] = [detail].[SOPNUMBE]
                INNER JOIN[dbo].[RM00102] AS[shiptoaddr]
                    ON[order].[PRSTADCD] = [shiptoaddr].[ADRSCODE]
                       AND[order].[CUSTNMBR] = [shiptoaddr].[CUSTNMBR]
                INNER JOIN[dbo].[RM00102] AS[billtoaddr]
                    ON[order].[PRBTADCD] = [billtoaddr].[ADRSCODE]
                       AND[order].[CUSTNMBR] = [billtoaddr].[CUSTNMBR]
                INNER JOIN[cp].[ReservedDocuments] AS[reserv]
                    ON[order].[SOPTYPE] = [reserv].[SOPTYPE]
                       AND[order].[SOPNUMBE] = [reserv].[SOPNUMBER]
            WHERE[order].[CUSTNMBR] = '{customerId}'
                  AND[order].[SOPTYPE] = 3";

        using (DbConnection db = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            var list = db.Query<OrderDto, OrderDetailDto, CustomerAddressDto, CustomerAddressDto, ReservedDocumentDto, OrderDto>(
                    sql,
                    (order, details, billto, shipto, reserve) =>
                    {
                        order.Details.Add(details);
                        order.Billto = billto;
                        order.Shipto = shipto;
                        order.Origin = reserve.DocumentOrigin;
                        
                        return order;
                    },
                    splitOn: "ITEMNMBR,BillToName,ShipToName,Origin", buffered: false)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Invodate)
                .ToList();

            return list;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_connectionFactory != null)
            {
                _logger.ForContext<DapperFunctions>().Information("Disposing DapperFunctions");
                //_connectionFactory.Dispose();
                _connectionFactory = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class OrderMap : EntityMap<OrderDto>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        Map(i => i.Soptype).ToColumn("SOPTYPE", false);
        Map(i => i.Sopnumbe).ToColumn("SOPNUMBE", false);
        Map(i => i.Invodate).ToColumn("INVODATE", false);
        Map(i => i.Actlship).ToColumn("ACTLSHIP", false);
        Map(i => i.Duedate).ToColumn("DUEDATE", false);
        Map(i => i.Locncode).ToColumn("LOCNCODE", false);
        Map(i => i.Custnmbr).ToColumn("CUSTNMBR", false);
        Map(i => i.Custname).ToColumn("CUSTNAME", false);
        Map(i => i.Slprsnid).ToColumn("SLPRSNID", false);
        Map(i => i.Pymtrcvd).ToColumn("PYMTRCVD", false);
        Map(i => i.Pymtrmid).ToColumn("PYMTRMID", false);
        Map(i => i.Subtotal).ToColumn("SUBTOTAL", false);
        Map(i => i.Frtamnt).ToColumn("FRTAMNT", false);
        Map(i => i.Taxamnt).ToColumn("TAXAMNT", false);
        Map(i => i.Docamnt).ToColumn("DOCAMNT", false);
    }
}

public class OrderDetailMap : EntityMap<OrderDetailDto>
{
    public OrderDetailMap()
    {
        Map(i => i.Itemnmbr).ToColumn("ITEMNMBR", false);
        Map(i => i.Soprtype).ToColumn("SOPTYPE", false);
        Map(i => i.Sopnumbe).ToColumn("SOPNUMBE", false);
        Map(i => i.ReqShipDate).ToColumn("ReqShipDate", false);
        Map(i => i.Itemdesc).ToColumn("ITEMDESC", false);
        Map(i => i.Uofm).ToColumn("UOFM", false);
        Map(i => i.Locncode).ToColumn("LOCNCODE", false);
        Map(i => i.Unitprce).ToColumn("UNITPRCE", false);
        Map(i => i.Xtndprce).ToColumn("XTNDPRCE", false);
        Map(i => i.Quantity).ToColumn("QUANTITY", false);
    }
}

public class BillToAddressMap : EntityMap<CustomerAddressDto>
{
    public BillToAddressMap()
    {
        Map(i => i.ShipToName).ToColumn("BillToName", false);
        Map(i => i.Custnmbr).ToColumn("CUSTNMBR", false);
        Map(i => i.Adrscode).ToColumn("ADRSCODE", false);
        Map(i => i.Cntcprsn).ToColumn("CNTCPRSN", false);
        Map(i => i.Address1).ToColumn("ADDRESS1", false);
        Map(i => i.Address2).ToColumn("ADDRESS2", false);
        Map(i => i.Address3).ToColumn("ADDRESS3", false);
        Map(i => i.Country).ToColumn("COUNTRY", false);
        Map(i => i.City).ToColumn("CITY", false);
        Map(i => i.State).ToColumn("STATE", false);
        Map(i => i.Zip).ToColumn("ZIP", false);
        Map(i => i.Phone1).ToColumn("PHONE1", false);
        Map(i => i.Phone2).ToColumn("PHONE2", false);
        Map(i => i.Phone3).ToColumn("PHONE3", false);
        Map(i => i.Fax).ToColumn("FAX", false);
    }
}

public class ShipToAddressMap : EntityMap<CustomerAddressDto>
{
    public ShipToAddressMap()
    {
        Map(i => i.ShipToName).ToColumn("ShipToName", false);
        Map(i => i.Custnmbr).ToColumn("CUSTNMBR", false);
        Map(i => i.Adrscode).ToColumn("ADRSCODE", false);
        Map(i => i.Cntcprsn).ToColumn("CNTCPRSN", false);
        Map(i => i.Address1).ToColumn("ADDRESS1", false);
        Map(i => i.Address2).ToColumn("ADDRESS2", false);
        Map(i => i.Address3).ToColumn("ADDRESS3", false);
        Map(i => i.Country).ToColumn("COUNTRY", false);
        Map(i => i.City).ToColumn("CITY", false);
        Map(i => i.State).ToColumn("STATE", false);
        Map(i => i.Zip).ToColumn("ZIP", false);
        Map(i => i.Phone1).ToColumn("PHONE1", false);
        Map(i => i.Phone2).ToColumn("PHONE2", false);
        Map(i => i.Phone3).ToColumn("PHONE3", false);
        Map(i => i.Fax).ToColumn("FAX", false);
    }
}

public class ReserveDocumentMap : EntityMap<ReservedDocumentDto>
{
    public ReserveDocumentMap()
    {
        Map(i => i.DocumentOrigin).ToColumn("Origin", false);
    }
}
```

The exception I am getting is `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I can provide the table definitions and dtos if needed. Any help diagnosing this will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As requested...

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at DataAccessLayer.DapperFunctions.<>c.<GetInvoicesMultiMappingOld>b__6_0(OrderDto order, OrderDetailDto details, CustomerAddressDto billto, CustomerAddressDto shipto, ReservedDocumentDto reserve) in D:\Projects\NewEcommerce\DataAccessLayer\DapperFunctions.cs:line 293
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<>c__DisplayClass160_0`8.<GenerateMapper>b__3(IDataReader r) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1568
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.MultiMapImpl[TFirst,TSecond,TThird,TFourth,TFifth,TSixth,TSeventh,TReturn](IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command, Delegate map, String splitOn, IDataReader reader, Identity identity, Boolean finalize)+MoveNext() in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1469
   at System.Linq.Set`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1 other)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator`1.FillSet()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator`1.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.ToList()
   at DataAccessLayer.DapperFunctions.GetInvoicesMultiMappingOld(String customerId) in D:\Projects\NewEcommerce\DataAccessLayer\DapperFunctions.cs:line 289
   at EcommerceWebAPI.Services.OrderService.GetAllInvoicesWithDapperOld(User user) in D:\Projects\NewEcommerce\NewEcommerce\Services\OrderService.cs:line 85
   at EcommerceWebAPI.Controllers.OrdersController.GetAllInvoicesWithDapperOld() in D:\Projects\NewEcommerce\NewEcommerce\Controllers\OrdersController.cs:line 114
   at lambda_method753(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at EcommerceWebAPI.Helpers.JwtMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IUserService userService) in D:\Projects\NewEcommerce\NewEcommerce\Helpers\JwtMiddleware.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.ResponseCachingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at EcommerceWebAPI.Startup.<>c.<<Configure>b__5_1>d.MoveNext() in D:\Projects\NewEcommerce\NewEcommerce\Startup.cs:line 209
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

... Line 293 in DapperFunctions.cs is: `order.Details.Add(details);`

Comment: Are we supposed to guess where the exception is thrown from?

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line. Does it throw on first occurrence, or some time after? Is `order` ever null? I suspect `details` may be null, the question is, is it always null, or are they simply missing in some of the records? It appears you may need some null checks in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jwdonahue put me on the right track...

In my OrderDto class I needed a constructor where I initialized my fields:

```cs
public OrderDto()
{
    Details = new List<OrderDetailDto>();
    Billto = new CustomerAddressDto();
    Shipto = new CustomerAddressDto();
    Origin = Origin.Unknown;
}
```

Yeah @jwdonahue! Everything works now.